# Unable to dispatch 'Excel.Application' using win32com, but able to dispatch 'Word' & 'Powerpoint'

Tags: python, win32com

I am unable to dispatch an Excel Application using win32com, but at the same time I am able to dispatch `Word.Application` & `powerpoint.application`.

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

I've also tried `app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")`

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Works on machine reboot.. strange!

Comment: is there any stacktrace ?

Comment: nope.. nothing.. just waits for eternity